# kubernetes affinity & anti-affinity

Tags: kubernetes, affinity

I have some little confusion. Please clarify.

In kubernetes we have concept called affinity and anti-affinity.

affinity provided two types

1: node affinity

2: pod-affinity

I want to know what are types are provided by anti-affinity?

I am thinking like anti-affinity is providing the type called podAntiAffinity, is it correct, actually i have a document for this but having little doubt. Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only `podAntiAffinity`. There is no `nodeAntiAffinity` and is not required. You can use `NotIn` or `DoesNotExist` operator with `nodeAffinity` to get behaviour similar to what you would expect if `nodeAntiAffinity` is available.

Comment: My concern is different!!!!                                                                                                        when we enter into below url we have a concept called affinity and anti-affinity, so actually The affinity feature consists of two types of affinity, “node affinity” and “inter-pod affinity/anti-affinity”. Now coming to my concern is what are the types are provided by anti-affinity feature.                                                                                               https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/

Comment: Is anti-affinity feature is providing any type. what i am thinking is anti-affinity feature is providing podAntiAfficnity, is it correct just need clarification only

Comment: Yes. `podAntiAffinity` is the only `antiAffinity` available.

Comment: Thanks your your clarification